# Primefaces blockUI does not work with selectOneRadio?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click `Yes`, the `fieldset` is blocked.
But, when I click `No`, Why the `fieldset` is unblocked? What I am missing?

```xhtml
<h:form id="blockUITest">
    <p:selectOneRadio style="width:130px;" onchange="blockUI(this.value);">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function blockUI(block) {
            if(block) {
                dataEntryBlockUI.show();
            } else {
                dataEntryBlockUI.hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <p:blockUI block="dataEntry" widgetVar="dataEntryBlockUI"/>
    <p:fieldset legend="Data Entry" id="dataEntry">
    </p:fieldset>               
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

itemValue is string and it is not an actual boolean value, so if you use it in if condition it would always be true because both true and false are non empty strings.
try this:

```
<h:form id="blockUITest">
    <p:selectOneRadio style="width:130px;" onchange="blockUI(this.value);">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function blockUI(block) {
            if(block==='true') {
                dataEntryBlockUI.show();
            } else {
                dataEntryBlockUI.hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <p:blockUI block="dataEntry" widgetVar="dataEntryBlockUI"/>
    <p:fieldset legend="Data Entry" id="dataEntry">
    </p:fieldset>               
</h:form>
```

there is also another way for using hide() and show() functions.
you can use jQuery to select blockUI element and then call these functions. But first you have to find the actual id of blockUI element.

```
$('#actualID').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I get one solution, javascript retrieve the element of `p:selectOneRadio` by `id`. After that check which radio is selected. It is work for me.

```xhtml
    <h:form id="blockUITest">
        <p:selectOneRadio style="width:130px;" onchange="blockUI();" id="xxx">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function blockUI() {
                var element1 = document.getElementById('blockUITest:xxx:0');
                if(element1.checked) {
                    dataEntryBlockUI.show();
                }
                var element2 = document.getElementById('blockUITest:xxx:1');
                if(element2.checked){
                    dataEntryBlockUI.hide();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <p:blockUI block="dataEntry" widgetVar="dataEntryBlockUI"/>
        <p:fieldset legend="Data Entry" id="dataEntry">
        </p:fieldset>               
    </h:form>
```